# admin-on-rest isomorphic server side rendering

Tags: admin-on-rest

I've been working on a project with team members to extend the 'Admin-On-Rest' React.js frontend framework. It has a lot of options and works great. There is however one aspect i'm missing, and it partially has to do with my lack of in depth knowledge about React.Js together with the 'Admin-On-Rest' framework.

**Is there a way to make the framework Isomorphic?**

I want to be able to render all* of it server side.

I've looked for documentation on how to to it in general on React applications and i understand that and it seems to work on small poc samples i make. however, doing the same on this frontend framework doesn't seem to go just as smooth.

Is it even possible to do it on 'Admin-On-Rest'? and if so, does anyone have pointers on where to start?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working ?

Comment: Everything is working from a functional perspective. I just want to basically run most of it (e.g. rendering , etc) on the server side instead of client side. i'm just wondering whether that's a default option, or whether it is rendered client side mostly by default

Comment: I meant, have you tried rendering it server side ? You'll probably have to specify your own history for the router as we use the hash one by default but it should work

Comment: this can be closed for now since the relevance isn't high anymore. By specifying the router history it does seem it's going to the right direction.